# spark apply function to columns in parallel

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parallel-processing, apache-spark-sql

Spark will process the data in parallel, but not the operations. In my DAG I want to call a function per column like
[Spark processing columns in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171070/spark-processing-columns-in-parallel) the values for each column could be calculated independently from other columns. Is there any way to achieve such parallelism via spark-SQL API? Utilizing window functions [Spark dynamic DAG is a lot slower and different from hard coded DAG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169873/spark-dynamic-dag-is-a-lot-slower-and-different-from-hard-coded-dag) helped to optimize the DAG by a lot but only executes in a serial fashion.

An example which contains a little bit more information can be found https://github.com/geoHeil/sparkContrastCoding

The minimum example below:

```
val df = Seq(
    (0, "A", "B", "C", "D"),
    (1, "A", "B", "C", "D"),
    (0, "d", "a", "jkl", "d"),
    (0, "d", "g", "C", "D"),
    (1, "A", "d", "t", "k"),
    (1, "d", "c", "C", "D"),
    (1, "c", "B", "C", "D")
  ).toDF("TARGET", "col1", "col2", "col3TooMany", "col4")

val inputToDrop = Seq("col3TooMany")
val inputToBias = Seq("col1", "col2")

val targetCounts = df.filter(df("TARGET") === 1).groupBy("TARGET").agg(count("TARGET").as("cnt_foo_eq_1"))
val newDF = df.toDF.join(broadcast(targetCounts), Seq("TARGET"), "left")
  newDF.cache
def handleBias(df: DataFrame, colName: String, target: String = target) = {
    val w1 = Window.partitionBy(colName)
    val w2 = Window.partitionBy(colName, target)

    df.withColumn("cnt_group", count("*").over(w2))
      .withColumn("pre2_" + colName, mean(target).over(w1))
      .withColumn("pre_" + colName, coalesce(min(col("cnt_group") / col("cnt_foo_eq_1")).over(w1), lit(0D)))
      .drop("cnt_group")
  }

val joinUDF = udf((newColumn: String, newValue: String, codingVariant: Int, results: Map[String, Map[String, Seq[Double]]]) => {
    results.get(newColumn) match {
      case Some(tt) => {
        val nestedArray = tt.getOrElse(newValue, Seq(0.0))
        if (codingVariant == 0) {
          nestedArray.head
        } else {
          nestedArray.last
        }
      }
      case None => throw new Exception("Column not contained in initial data frame")
    }
  })
```

Now I want to apply my `handleBias` function to all the columns, unfortunately, this is not executed in parallel.

```
val res = (inputToDrop ++ inputToBias).toSet.foldLeft(newDF) {
    (currentDF, colName) =>
      {
        logger.info("using col " + colName)
        handleBias(currentDF, colName)
      }
  }
    .drop("cnt_foo_eq_1")

val combined = ((inputToDrop ++ inputToBias).toSet).foldLeft(res) {
    (currentDF, colName) =>
      {
        currentDF
          .withColumn("combined_" + colName, map(col(colName), array(col("pre_" + colName), col("pre2_" + colName))))
      }
  }

val columnsToUse = combined
    .select(combined.columns
      .filter(_.startsWith("combined_"))
      map (combined(_)): _*)

val newNames = columnsToUse.columns.map(_.split("combined_").last)
val renamed = columnsToUse.toDF(newNames: _*)

val cols = renamed.columns
val localData = renamed.collect

val columnsMap = cols.map { colName =>
    colName -> localData.flatMap(_.getAs[Map[String, Seq[Double]]](colName)).toMap
}.toMap
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> values for each column could be calculated independently from other columns

While it is true it doesn't really help your case. You can generate a number of independent `DataFrames`, each one with its own additions, but it doesn't mean you can automatically combine this into a single execution plan.

Each application of `handleBias` shuffles your data twice and output `DataFrames` don't have the same data distribution as the parent `DataFrame`. This is why when you `fold` over the list of columns each addition has to be performed separately.

**Theoretically** you could design a pipeline which can be expressed (with *pseudocode*) like this:

- add unique id:

  ```
  df_with_id = df.withColumn("id", unique_id())
  ```
- compute each df independently and convert to *wide* format:

  ```
  dfs = for (c in columns) 
    yield handle_bias(df, c).withColumn(
      "pres", explode([(pre_name, pre_value), (pre2_name, pre2_value)])
    )
  ```
- union all partial results:

  ```
  combined = dfs.reduce(union)
  ```
- pivot to convert from long to wide format:

  ```
  combined.groupBy("id").pivot("pres._1").agg(first("pres._2"))
  ```

but I doubt it is worth all the fuss. The process you use is extremely heavy as it is and requires a significant network and disk IO.

If number of total levels (`sum count(distinct x)) for x in columns)`) is relatively low you can try to compute all statistics with a single pass using for example `aggregateByKey` with `Map[Tuple2[_, _], StatCounter]` otherwise consider downsampling to the level where you can compute statistics locally.